# Magento 1 Rest call causes php error on every second call

Tags: php, magento, azure-webapps

I am facing a problem, I can't wrap my head around.

I got the following script

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

$apiResources = "products?limit=2";
$isAdminUser = true;
$adminUrl = "admin";
$host = $_GET["url"]; 
$token = $_GET["token"]; 
$secret = $_GET["secret"]; 
$consumerKey = $_GET["consumerkey"];
$consumerSecret = $_GET["consumersecret"]; 
$apiUrl = $host . "api/rest/";


$authType = OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_AUTHORIZATION;
$oauthClient = new OAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1, $authType);
$oauthClient->enableDebug();
$oauthClient->setToken($token, $secret);
$resourceUrl = $apiUrl.$apiResources;
$oauthClient->fetch($resourceUrl, array(), 'GET', array('Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'Accept' => '*/*'));
$productsList = json_decode($oauthClient->getLastResponse());
$productsList = $oauthClient->getLastResponse();
echo "<pre>";
print_r($productsList);
echo "</pre>";
```

Whenever I run it locally on my Wampserver it works as expected and return a json lists of products from a Magento 1 store placed online no matter how many times I call it.
When I run the same script on my php server towards the same magento 1 store, it only works every second time. Even if I run incognito mode from the browser, it only works every second time. The logs contains no information and the page just shows:

`The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.`

Locally I run Wamp 3.2 with php version 7.1.9
On my php server which runs on an Azure WebApp I run 7.3.14

Can anyone give my any ideas as to what is the problem.